# Unable to invoke the method with variable arguments using reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

When the method **m** is    ( *where m is the method to be invoked using reflection* )

```
public static Optional<JsonNode> concat(ObjectNode entity, String separator, String fieldName1,
          String fieldName2)
```

Then i am able to get the computed value ( *where computed value is the value obtained using reflection )*

While, when the method **m** is

```
public static Optional<JsonNode> concat(ObjectNode entity, String ...separatorAndField)
```

then i am able not able to get the computed value

I am invoking the method as follows:-

```
   computedValue = (Optional<JsonNode>) m.invoke(null, methodArgs);
```

Note:- *methodArgs is declared as an object array.*

Comment: "methodArgs is declared as an object array" **Show, don't tell**.

Comment: Added the more information @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the difference between invoking a varargs and a non-varargs static method via reflection:

```
class Main
{
    public static void foo(String fieldName1, String fieldName2)
    {
        System.out.println(fieldName1 + "," + fieldName2);
    }

    public static void bar(String... fields)
    {
        System.out.println(String.join(",", fields));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final Method foo = Main.class.getMethod("foo", String.class, String.class);
        foo.invoke(null, "aaa", "bbb");

        final Method bar = Main.class.getMethod("bar", String[].class);
        bar.invoke(null, (Object) new String[] {"ccc", "ddd", "eee"});
    }
}
```

Output:

```
aaa,bbb
ccc,ddd,eee
```